# Deriving the recurrence for the number of strings of length n?

Tags: recurrence-relations

(a) Let $P_n$ be the number of strings of length n formed from letters A, B, C, E, O, that do not contain two consecutive consonants (that is, B or C). For example, AABOCA and BACOOEBO satisfy this condition, while AABCEC does not. Derive a recurrence relation for the numbers $P_n$. You need to provide a complete justification for this recurrence. (But you do not need to solve it.)

Ok so I found values for n = 0, 1, 2 by hand, and I got $P_0$ = 1, $P_1$ = 5, and $P_2$ = 21. From that I figured the recurrence is $P_n$ = 4$P_{n - 1}$ + 1. I am not sure if the initial values I calculated are correct or if the recurrence is derived is correct either. I am hoping someone here can let me know if I am thinking correctly and point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find a recurrence relation for the number of ternary strings of length n that do not contain two consecutive 0s or two consecutive 1s.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1322767/find-a-recurrence-relation-for-the-number-of-ternary-strings-of-length-n-that-do)

Answer (score 1):

See if you can fill in the gaps.

A word of the required type of length $n$ must consist of

> any one of $3$ vowels, followed by word of the same type with length $n$: there are $3P_{n-1}$ possibilities;

or

> any one of $2$ consonants, followed by ... , followed by a word of the same type with length ... : there are ... possibilities.

Therefore, $P_n=\ ...$

Your initial values are correct.

Comment: Ok, so I figured it is $3P_{n-1}$ + $6P_{n-2}$. I am not understanding the 6 though. I am not really sure how I would explain that? Choose from 2 vowels followed by choosing from 3 vowels?

Comment: If you fill in the gaps in the second part of my answer I think you will understand it.